# Android Espresso Testing - How can I test android's native functionality like widget,add as new title using espresso

Tags: android-widget, android-espresso, ui-automation, android-testing, android-uiautomator

Is there any options to test android's native functionality such as widgets,add as new tile using espresso. Else we have to come out of espresso and to use UIAUTOMATOR. If has to use Uiautomator, How to do that? Any one done or doing it?

Comment: You need UiAutomator for this. Checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191745/uiautomator-add-widget-to-home-screen

Comment: @Rakib this is not much useful to me. How Can I test whether the widget is properly inserted and working finely or not?